# Custom block save does not match due to stripped slashes from br tag and added figure tag around images

Tags: block-editor

I'm having a problem where my `<br/>` tags (valid JSX) get stripped to `<br>` upon save which makes the editor state that the block is not the same causing it to be invalid.

This means that a user cannot update the block without deleting and re-entering all the data again which is fairly tedious.

**Save Text**

```
return ( <div>
            <RichText.Content className={subheadingClass} tagName="p" value={attributes.subheading}/>
            <RichText.Content className={subsubheadingClass} tagName="p" value={attributes.subsubheading}/>
            <br/><br/>
            <RichText.Content className={paragraphClass} tagName="p" value={attributes.paragraph}/>
         </div>
);
```

I also have another problem with my image tags being surrounded by a `<figure>` tag.

Is there a way to stop the figure tag being wrapped around my images?

**Save Image**

```
<img className={carouselClass} data-image-id={image.id} src={image.url} alt {image.alt} uk-cover/>
```

I am stumped as to how to get past the `<br>` and what causes `<figure>` to also be incorrect. Help on either of these would be appreciated.

The WordPress version is 5.0.3.

Comment: You need to share the full block code for us to understand the problem and suggest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error which is shown by WordPress graphically **is not the same** output that you actually get from the block.

Open up the browser's console, and you will see the **actual** expected and outcome.

Do a quick diff between the two outputs and you should be able to find your mismatch.

The break tags and figure wrapping of images only occurred in the UI error and not in practice.